# Java - split image into jigsaw pieces

Tags: java, android, andengine

I need to create a jigsaw puzzle game. I've already done this in the past using AndEngine, however I've only cut texture into rectangles. Now I need to cut it into proper jigsaw pieces. How can I do that?

Comment: Really broad. Anyway, by searching googling, you'll find a lot of open source stuff on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the texture into rectangles but for every rectangle take extra space. So you would have a lot of rectangles which overlap each other.
Then you need to have some set of patterns for jigsaw edges (black and white images or you can call it a mask) and generate a mask for every rectangle using those patterns.
The algorithm would be:
create a mask with a size of rectangle and initialise it with white color. 
Then choose edge pattens based on rectangle-neighbors if they are initialised or choose edges randomly if neighbors are not yet initialize. 
After you chose the patterns, draw them on a mask for every side. So in the end you would have a mask with a shape of a jigsaw piece. white color = visible, black color - transparent.
Then apply the mask to the rectangle when you draw it.
And bare in mind that you don't stack these rectangles based on their actual size, but stack in a way that they would overlay each other...

P.S. I hope you understood what I was trying to say. Sorry, English is not my native language...